# How to write a text in a square drawn with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I've used tikz to draw a digram like this:

```
$$\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0.6,0) -- (0.6,0.6) -- (0,0.6) -- (0,0);
\draw (0.6,0) -- (1.2,0) -- (1.2,0.6) -- (0.6,0.6) -- (0.6,0);
\draw (1.2,0) -- (1.8,0) -- (1.8,0.6) -- (1.2,0.6) -- (1.2,0);
\draw (1.8,0) -- (2.4,0) -- (2.4,0.6) -- (1.8,0.6) -- (1.8,0);
\draw (0,-0.6) -- (0.6,-0.6) -- (0.6,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,-0.6);
\draw (0.6,-0.6) -- (1.2,-0.6) -- (1.2,0) -- (0.6,0) -- (0.6,-0.6);
\draw (1.2,-0.6) -- (1.8,-0.6) -- (1.8,0) -- (1.2,0) -- (1.2,-0.6);
\draw (0,-1.2) -- (0.6,-1.2) -- (0.6,-0.6) -- (0,-0.6) -- (0,-1.2);
\draw (0,-1.8) -- (0.6,-1.8) -- (0.6,-1.2) -- (0,-1.2) -- (0,-1.8);
\end{tikzpicture}$$
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

But now I want to put a text in the center of each cell or square. I don't know how to do this. I tried the tricks in similar posts, but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which tricks did you try? If you want to put text in boxes, maybe start with nodes instead of drawing squares. Also, note that `tikzpicture` environments don't need math mode.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you! There was a command with \placeTextBox but when I tried it, nothing showed up.  Another one is the \node in tikzpicture but I don't fully understand how it works, that's probably why:)

Comment: I definitely would use a matrix of nodes, like in Zarko's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With use of `matrix` library:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,
         nodes={draw, minimum size=1.4em, anchor=center},
         column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
{
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4   \\
 5 & 6 & 7 &     \\
 8 &   &   &     \\
 9 &   &   &     \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `positioning` library to make things easier. Then position the nodes and use their label text. Note that you can probably only fit about 3 characters in a 6mm square, but you can easily adjust the size by changing `minimum size`.

[image]

Using `-\pgflinewidth` for the `node distance` will overlap the squares on their borders.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, minimum size=6mm, inner sep=0}, node distance=-\pgflinewidth]
\node(a1){1};
\node[right=of a1](a2){2};
\node[right=of a2](a3){3};
\node[right=of a3](a4){4};
\node[below=of a1](b1){5};
\node[right=of b1](b2){6};
\node[right=of b2](b3){7};
\node[below=of b1](c1){8};
\node[below=of c1](d1){9};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```